# Finding a maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

What is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$? $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$, since 5 is not coprime to itself, so where would I go from here?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is not the same as $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$, they are not isomorphic.

Comment: @CPM Yeah my mistake, 5 isn't coprime to 5 so they can't be isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$.  Then $M$ is maximal if and only if $R/M$ is a field.  So maximal ideals would look like $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times (0)$ or $(0) \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ since those quotients are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ which is a field.

Adding on based on the OP comments.

If $R=R_1 \times R_2$ where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are commutative rings with $1$, then the maximal ideals of $R$ are of the form $M_1 \times R_2$ or $R_1 \times M_2$ where $M_1$ is a maximal ideal of $R_1$ and $M_2$ is a maximal ideal of $R_2$.

Comment: So like $((0,k))$ and $((k,0))$ are maximal ideals?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, so the only ideals in a field are $(0)$ or the whole field.  That doesn't leave too many choices for ideals in the factors of the direct product.

Comment: You do not explain why these are the only maximal ideals.

Comment: Every ideal $I$, in a ring $R=R_1 \times R_2$ is of the form $I=I_1 \times I_2$ where $I_i$ is an ideal of $R_i$.